# I cannot remove the suspension of CloudSQL instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I hope anyone here will able to help me in how to remove the suspension of my CloudSQL, when I contacted the billing support and I don't have any more problem with billing and they just provided this reference as next step to find out https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/diagnose-issues?authuser=3&_ga=2.216151318.-1299773106.1599446258&_gac=1.86514794.1597133070.Cj0KCQjwg8n5BRCdARIsALxKb94Pozi5td7sJNVzgUwa3adOVvLzYIJibZLh5BBzlzNQQoFPwe3DIf8aAsnMEALw_wcB#suspended but this is too technical for me, which I just need to start my CloudSQL instance. I was able to create a new instance just to make sure I have the right permissions. So what could be the problem? Practically I don't want to pay for the expensive Support in just this inquiry.

Hope there is some engineer who can help me about this or if they experienced the same.

Comment: What's the current status of your instance? Did you try to restart it?

Comment: @TasosV currently it has the red warding icon, it show the Suspended when I hover it. When I select the Restart or Stop button it display the following message

The attempted action failed, please try again.
Request ID: 8998983681623162936123

Comment: This looks like an issue should be handled either from the support team, cause your status looks stuck there. I would open an [PIT issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/savedsearches/559773?q=(componentid:187202%2B%20status:open)%20OR%20(componentid:187065%2B%20customfield82940:%22Cloud%20SQL%22%20status:open)) and I would wait for some help. Hope it helps.

Comment: Based on the documentation they provided:

* Suspended state
There are various reasons why Cloud SQL may suspend an instance, including:

1. Billing issues
2. KMS key issues
- Do I used this to setup the CloudSQL
3. Legal issues
- I believe I didn't do anything related to it
4. Operational issues
- I didn't found any error logs

Please and I hope any Google Cloud Engineer will able to help me about this issue. 

I don't think that it is necessary, Cloud SQL users with Platinum, Gold, or Silver support packages can contact our support team directly about suspended instances.

Comment: KMS key issues refer to instances which have been disabled because the KMS key has been disabled. If you attempted to create your instance with [CMEK enabled](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/configure-cmek?authuser=3#createcmekinstance), this may be a possibility. Please also find out more about [CMEK](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/cmek?authuser=3) in the corresponding public documentation if you are unsure. It is essential cryptographic keys used to access the Cloud SQL data.

Comment: In order to appropriately determine the issue it would be highly recommended to open a [PIT issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/savedsearches/559773?q=(componentid:187202%2B%20status:open)%20OR%20(componentid:187065%2B%20customfield82940:%22Cloud%20SQL%22%20status:open)) as TasosV recommended as it would then be possible to identify whether this issue is caused by the other possibilities listed. Some of our investigations will require in-depth investigation and this platform will be much more suitable for such interactions.

Comment: There may be potential for sensitive private information of which we may need access, which will be much more secure when dealt with on Public tracker as we can create private components so that this information is not leaked to the community.

Comment: Please identify whether you have enable CMEK on your Cloud SQL instance, and if this is not the case please identify such and create a PIT for further investigation.

Comment: The Google Cloud engineering team was able to resolve this reported issue. It doesn't mention what really the cause of this issue. But as of now I was able to Stop and Restart again my CloudSQL instance.

Answer (score 1):

Just for transparency and in a try to help other I will post my comment as an answer to this post.

This kind of issue should be handled from the support team, either by opening a support ticket if you own a support package, or by opening a [Public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/savedsearches/559773?q=(componentid:187202%2B%20status:open)%20OR%20(componentid:187065%2B%20customfield82940:%22Cloud%20SQL%22%20status:open)) under the appropriate component.